# Can not add Apple client ID to Firebase invites intent on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

When creating Firebase invite intent I try to add link to iOS app as described in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android#customize-the-invitation):

```
    intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(context.getString(R.string.invitation_title))
            .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.invitation_message))
                .setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication(
                        AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder.PlatformMode.PROJECT_PLATFORM_IOS,
                        "1059710961")
            .build();
```

"1059710961" and "mobi.appintheair.wifi" both cause the same error:

```
AppInviteAgent: Create invitations failed due to error code: 3
AppInviteAgent: Target client ID must include non-empty and valid client ID: 1059710961. (APPINVITE_CLIENT_ID_ERROR)
```

What is the correct format for this parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this client ID you have to do the following:

1. Register you iOS app in the Firebase Console
2. Download `GoogleServices-Info.plist` for iOS app as we download `google-services.json` for Android
3. Look in it and found value for the key `CLIENT_ID` (will be something like this `123456789012-abababababababababababababababab.apps.googleusercontent.com`)
4. Add it to builder:

   ```
   intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(context.getString(R.string.invitation_title))
       ............
       .setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication(
           AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder.PlatformMode.PROJECT_PLATFORM_IOS,
           "123456789012-abababababababababababababababab.apps.googleusercontent.com")
       .build();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

the client_id is the one in the plist you download from the firebase console for your iOS app